# Mobx react observable data change not rerendering react

Tags: sockets, mobx

I am writing an observable object from a socket event that is emitted from the server, but I just can't figure a way out to change the data in the variable that it is observing to cause a rerender in the front-end.

Here is what my stores look like

```
import { observable } from "mobx";
import io from "socket.io-client";

class SocketStore {

    @observable socket = null;

    constructor(socket) {
        this.socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
    }
}

export default new SocketStore();
```

.

```
    import { observable } from "mobx";
    import SocketStore from './SocketStore';

    class NameStore {

        @observable nameData = {};
        @observable state = "pending";

        retrieveData() {
            if (this.state === "pending") {
                SocketStore.socket.on('send data', this.processData);
            }
        }

        processData(data) {
            this.d = Date.now();
            this.nameData = data;
            this.state = "completed";

            console.log(this.nameData);
            console.log (String(Date

.now() - this.d) + " Seconds");
    }
}

export default new NameStore();
```

Why won't my UI re-render?

Comment: are you calling processData(data) from retrieveData() ?

Comment: @ChiragSharma yes because it's a callback.

Comment: This seems to happen a lot so I thought I would ask. Is your component wrapped by the observer HOC?

Comment: @WilliamChou Yes. I just figured it out, I had to structure it differently because of the socket. I need to use @ actions to set the observable. new to mobx here, so sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 0):

I had to structure it differently because of the socket. I need to use @actions to set the observable. new to mobx here, so sorry for the noob question.

So it would basically look like this

```
class NameStore {

    @observable nameData = {};
    @observable state = "pending";

    @action setClientData(nameInfo) {
        this.nameData = nameInfo;
    }

    @action setState(state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```